# Refactoring public methods to another class

Tags: c#, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I have a C# win form which serves as the GUI for my application. In the form code I've written all the public methods which used by the form events. Now I need to refactor all those public methods to another **static** class. I've studied 7 methods for refactoring built-in to VS2010 ([See here](http://p2p.wrox.com/content/articles/7-refactoring-methods-visual-studio-2010)). I also used the Extract interface method but, I still need to implement a interface method before initializing. My question is; Is there any facility in the Visual studio 2010 to do this? [Like This](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio does not support the Extract Class refactoring. The latest versions of ReSharper do.

Answer (score 0):

1 -Static classes can not implement interfaces so rule out this possibility.

2- You can not mock static class.

VS 2010 does not have Extract Class refactoring technique so you need to consider using ReSharper or other refatcoring tools

Comment: I didn't go for Option 1. I said I just tried that Extract interface INSTEAD static class extraction.